# What does this line mean in my tape status on my linux system?

Tags: linux, redhat, scsi

mt -f /dev/st0 status

SCSI 2 tape drive:

File number=0, block number=0, partition=0.

Tape block size 512 bytes. Density code 0x30 (AIT-1 or MLR3).

Soft error count since last status=0 <---------------------

General status bits on (41010000):

BOT ONLINE IM_REP_EN

I have a script that grabs errors and reports them through our email server and the only error it is sending back is this line so I'm curious on what it is.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Very sorry about that. I'll move the question over there.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

[image]

Extracted from [this manual](https://books.google.es/books?id=nvnHAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA420&lpg=PA420&dq=Density+code+0x30&source=bl&ots=OEzhjcHf6r&sig=0YjhUeZV1-HEZhPiYghyJwCHQw8&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv_czrovnQAhVBChoKHcxwAggQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=Density%20code%200x30&f=false)

Anyway, this question is not for this forum. This is for development. Your question should be answered with more accuracy on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or any other.